# Hit multiple url without getting response in php

Tags: php, curl

I have multiple urls in my database and want to hit them without getting response using php.

is there any way to do this..

Comment: You can do that in whatever language you can imagine that runs on servers these days - but if your server runs PHP and nothign else than your choice is limited to that one language

Comment: I want to hit urls from backend with out using database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function multiUrlUsingCurl($urls)
{
        $sg = curl_multi_init();

        $results = array();
        foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {

            $results[$key] = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($results[$key], array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
            ));

            curl_multi_add_handle($sg, $results[$key]);
        }

        $flag = null;
        do {
            $status = curl_multi_exec($sg, $flag);
        }
        while ($flag);

        foreach ($results as $res) {
            echo curl_multi_getcontent($res);
            curl_multi_remove_handle($sg, $res);
            curl_close($res);
        }

        curl_multi_close($sg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to save your entries in a file, either as ASCII format or serialized string like json or you could save it as xml. But i suggest you save it like a json string. Its pretty straightforward.

EDIT:

A quick snippet to help you get started:

```
function getUrlList($fileName)
{
    if(file_exists($fileName)) {
        return json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);
    }
    return array();
}

function saveUrl($fileName, $newUrl)
{
    if(file_exists($fileName)) {
        $list = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);
        $list = array_merge($list, $newUrl);
        file_put_contents($fileName, json_encode($list));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$fileName = 'myFileDB.json';
$UrlToSave = array('id' => uniqid(), 'url' => someUrlYouWantToSave);
saveUrl($fileName, $urlToSave);    // To save Url

// To get List
$urlsList = getUrlList($fileName);
```

From there you can extend the functionality to edit the urls or have some other actions to manipulate data. You have to also make sure that you have an empty json string in the file you want to save the url into. Either you write some logic to do that or for simplicity reasons put {} in a file.

Comment: what will be next after saving entries in a file ?? please explain